# Update table from stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have stored procedure where I update my table :

```
UPDATE myTbl
SET [first_name] = @first_name,  
    [second_name] = @second_name,  
    [faculty] = @faculty,
    [age] = @age
    WHERE [id] = @id
```

When I call a stored procedure and when passed all of the parameters that update works. Now I want to update the table so if I do not enter all the values ​​to update, updated, only those which I introduced, and which are not introduced remained the same.

Comment: Do the parameters have default values of `NULL`, e.g. `@first_name as varchar(64) = NULL`? Do you call the procedure without some parameters?

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE myTbl
SET [first_name] = IsNull(@first_name, first_name),  
    [second_name] = IsNull(@second_name, second_name),  
    [faculty] = IsNull(@faculty, faculty),
    [age] = IsNull(@age, age),
    WHERE [id] = @id
```

Comment: thank you for anwering.I call procedure like exec myProce 'Tom','','',12   during call procedure, when i dont type any values which i dont want to update , it always updates itself and the tables getting empty again and again

Comment: @GeoVIP There is a difference between NULL and a blank string ('').  If you don't want to update a value you should do exec myProce 'Tom', NULL, NULL, 12.  Otherwise, the update will update to the blank string ('').

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE myTbl
SET
    [first_name] = ISNULL(@first_name,  [first_name])
    , [second_name] = ISNULL(@second_name,  [second_name])
    , [faculty] = ISNULL(@faculty, [faculty])
    , [age] = ISNULL(@age, [age])
WHERE [id] = @id
```

Comment: thank you for anwering.I call procedure like exec myProce 'Tom','','',12   during call procedure, when i dont type any values which i dont want to update , it always updates itself and the tables getting empty again and again

Comment: @GeoVIP - There it is: _wishful programming_. You don't really mean `''` and you hope it won't notice, but you are explicitly telling it to set the columns to empty strings. That's quite different from defining NULL defaults and calling `exec myProce 'Tom', , , 12`.

Answer (score 0):

Right before you run the update, you can run a SELECT statement to extract all of the values from the table.

Also, you verify all of the values passed to the stored procedure, and if they're null, you use the selected values in your update statement.